# Does server's location affect players' ping?

Tags: server, location, ping, latency, low-latency

I want to reduce a latency for my players in a multiplayer game.

Would it be beneficial to make a server in each continent to reduce latency? E.g. players are in US, but the server is in Europe, so I make it be in US.

**How big could the difference be?**

Comment: Besides the answer, detailed on transport-part of the latency, below, you may be interested in this post on how real-time systems are affected -- both by the transport + application -- **latency** and **latency jitter** -- depicted in animated graphs to show **the scale of the problem `>>>`** http://stackoverflow.com/a/36954113/3666197

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely, the closest your server is from the user the better the ping is because the travelling distance / time is reduced.
Specially between Europe and America, because of the sea ;)

The difference really depend on your server, but at least 150ms I think.

Comment: so how big is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

### Cable . . . ( raw-fiber on Layer 1 [PHY] ) mileage rulez

Recent transatlantic cables ( deploying shorter fibre-meandres in a tighter inner-tubing ) benefit from about the 2012+ generation of cables **shorter** transatlantic **latencies** somewhere **under 60 milliseconds**, according to [Hibernia Atlantic.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernia_Networks)
[image]

One has also to account for lambda-signal amplification and retiming units, that add some additional Layer 1 [PMD] latency overheads down the road.

---

### Yes, but...

**`ping`** is a trivial tool to test **`RTT`** records ( a packet round-trip-time  ) derived from **counting a time, the packet proceeds through a network infrastructure there and back**.

Thus sending such `ping` packet across a few meter cable distance would typically cost less time than having to wait till another such packet makes it to a target on the opposite side of the Globe and has next successfully crawled back again, **but...** as Heraclitus from Ephesos **wisdom: "You can't step twice into the same river"** .. repeating the ping probes to the same target will yield in many principally very different time-delays ( **latencies are non-stationary** ).

But there are many additional cardinal issues, besides the geographical distance from A-to-B, that influence the end-to-end latency ( and an expected smoothness ) of the application-layer services.

### What bothers?

**Transport network congestions** ( if actual traffic overloads an underlying network capacities, buffering delays and/or packet drops start to occur )

**Packet re-transmission**(s) ( if any packet got lost, the opposite side will ask for re-transmission, packets received in the meantime are being recorded for reception, but only **after some remarkably longer time**, the missing packet arrives, for which the receiving process was yet waiting, because without a packet 6, one cannot decode the full message and packets 7, 8, 9, 10, ... simply had to wait until the #6 was asked for by the receiver's side at the sender's side, was re-transmitted from the sender's side and have made it again, hopefully with a successful delivery this time, to the receiver's hands to fit the puzzle-gap. **That costs a lot more time, than a smooth error-free data-flow** )

**Selective class-of-traffic prioritisation** ( if your class-of-traffic is not prioritised, your packets will be policed to wait in queues, until higher priorities allow for some more lower-priority traffic to fit in )

**Packet deliveries do not guarantee to take the same path** over the same network-vectors and individual packets can be, in general, transported over multiple different trajectories ( **add** various prioritisation policies + various buffering drop-outs + various intermittent congestions and spurious flows ... and the resulting **latency *per se* + timing variance**, i.e. the uncertainty of a final delivery time of the next packet only grows up and up ).

Last but not least, the **server system processing bottlenecks**. Fine-tuning a server to avoid any such adverse effect ( performance bottlenecks and even worse, any blocking-state episode(s) ) belongs to a **professional controlled-latency infrastructure design & maintenance.**

---

### The Devil comes next!

You might have already noticed, that besides a **static latency** scale ( demonstrated by **`ping`** ) realistic gaming is even more adversely affected by **latency jitter** ... as an in-game context magically UFO-es forwards and back in `TimeDOMAIN` ... which cause unrealistically jumping planes right in front of your aiming cross, "shivering" characters, deadly enemy-fire bullets that causes one's damages without ever seen / a yet visible attacker body and similar disturbing artefacts.

**Server-colocation proximity** *per se* will help in the **former**, but will let on you to fight the **latter**